# Trying to install Haskell: C Compiler not working

Tags: macos, haskell, gcc

On my MacOS 11.6.2 (Big Sur), I am trying to install Haskell, but my C compiler is not working. I've reinstalled XCode already as some other posts mention, and I ran a test on a simple C program using: `gcc -o main main.c` and got this error:

> "ld: unsupported tapi file type '!tapi-tbd' in YAML file '/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/SDKs/MacOSX11.sdk/usr/lib/libSystem.tbd' for architecture x86_64
> collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status"

`$ which gcc`: /usr/local/bin/gcc

`$ gcc --version`: gcc (Homebrew GCC 12.2.0) 12.2.0

Associated installation error:

```
[ Info  ] Installing GHC (this may take a while)
[ ghc-configure ] configure: Xcode version component 2: 2
[ ghc-configure ] checking for gcc... gcc
[ ghc-configure ] checking whether the C compiler works... no
[ ghc-configure ] configure: error: in `/Users/chandyego84/.ghcup/tmp...
[ ghc-configure ] configure: error: C compiler cannot create executab...
[ ghc-configure ] See `config.log' for more details
[ Error ] Process "sh" with arguments ["./configure",
[ ...   ]                              "--prefix=/Users/chandyego84/.ghcup/ghc/9.2.5",
[ ...   ]                              "--disable-ld-override"] failed with exit code 77.
```

ghc-configure.log:

```
checking host system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
checking target system type... x86_64-apple-darwin20.6.0
Build platform inferred as: x86_64-apple-darwin
Host platform inferred as: x86_64-apple-darwin
Target platform inferred as: x86_64-apple-darwin
GHC build  : x86_64-apple-darwin
GHC host   : x86_64-apple-darwin
GHC target : x86_64-apple-darwin
LLVM target: x86_64-apple-darwin
checking for path to top of build tree... /Users/chandyego84/.ghcup/tmp/ghcup-78f66d443cb0bfcc/ghc-9.2.5-x86_64-apple-darwin
checking for a BSD-compatible install... /usr/bin/install -c
checking whether ln -s works... yes
checking for gsed... sed
checking for python3... /Users/chandyego84/anaconda3/bin/python3
checking Xcode version... 13.2.1
configure: Xcode version component 1: 13
configure: Xcode version component 2: 2
checking for gcc... gcc
checking whether the C compiler works... no
configure: error: in `/Users/chandyego84/.ghcup/tmp/ghcup-78f66d443cb0bfcc/ghc-9.2.5-x86_64-apple-darwin':
configure: error: C compiler cannot create executables
```

Comment: Update: If I do the gcc command in VSCode terminal it works, but it doesn't work on my regular terminal..

Comment: This problem doesn't really seem to have anything to do with Haskell.

Comment: Hypothesis: When you run in VS Code, your shell's dotfiles aren't read  and you're using the "default gcc", which is just a symlink to clang (try `gcc --version` and look). When you run in the shell, the configuration is broken in such a way that you use a mixture of gcc and Apple's command line tools.